# 1h diff between @timestamp and timestamp field in Elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash

I use Elasticsearch with Docker, Logstash and Filebeat.

Here is the problem in my logs :

```
@timestamp: January 2nd 2018, 11:43:38.000
timestamp: Jan 2 10:43:38
```

Here is my logstash.conf

```
filter {
    ...
    syslog_pri { } 

        grok {
        match => [
              "message", '%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:dockerhost} %{DATA:conteneur}(?:\[%{POSINT:pid}\])?:?:( time="%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}")?( level=%{LOGLEVEL:severity})?( msg=)?%{GREEDYDATA:message}',
]
      }

      date { match => ["[timestamp]", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ] }
    }
    ...
```

I also mounted /etc/localtime so, when I connect inside docker container with:

```
docker exec -it d123456d8 bash
$ date
```

`date` command is giving me the correct date / time

What am I not seeing ?

Comment: are you viewing the timestamp in kibana?

Comment: Yes I do. I also checked date in Kibana container

Comment: sounds like timezone in kibana web.

Setting-->Advanced---> DateFormat:tz

Comment: I have no Advanced sumenu in settings... Just Font size and autocomplete...

Comment: And I can only access it in Dev Tools page

Comment: sorry now I found it

Comment: DateFormat:tz is set to Browser. When I enter Date() in Firefox console debugger, date is OK; So I guess this setting is ok